# Flashvars in JW player 6

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, akamai

I am migrating from JW player 5 to JW player 6. In 5 I am using flashvars to integrate akamai provider using swfobject, but embedding using swfobject is not supported in 6.
Akamai has provided new plugin but not sure how to pass these in version 6.

Has anyone successfully integrated or have any idea how to pass these flashvars in version 6?
Nothing regarding this is mentioned in user guide by akamai.

**UPDATE**

After seeing Ethan's answer, I am doing this, now I get "No playable sources found" error,

```js
jwplayer('content_video').setup({
    'file': video_file_url,
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '674',
    'height': '451',
    'primary': 'flash',
    'provider': 'http://players.edgesuite.net/flash/plugins/jw/v2.11/jw6/AkamaiAdvancedJWStreamProvider.swf'
});
```

The `video_file_url` is url given by akamai, it is something like the following:

```html
http://domain.akamaihd.net/i/me/1988,_240p,.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1356418433~exp=1356420233~acl=/*~hmac=e534f60717c8b710dfdkfjkdfkvmffgklbb8844dc9d2cbce22c816
```

Let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted Akamai and got it working, below is the sample taken directly from their sample file.

```js
jwplayer("player").setup({
    playlist: [{
        file: 'http://multiformatlive-f.akamaihd.net/demostream_1_,300~300,800~800,1200~1200,@2131.usmil',
        provider: "AkamaiAdvancedJWStreamProvider.swf",
        type:'mp4'
    }],
    width:640,
    height:360,
    primary: "flash",

    //<----------------- RTMP CONFIG TAGS ---------------------------->
    //, retryLive:true
    //, retryInterval:5
    //, liveTimeout:5
    //, connectionAttemptInterval:5
    //, connectAuthParams:'connectionAuthToken'
    //, streamAuthParams:'auth=livestreamAuthToken'
    //<----------------- Works on all network types ---------------------------->
    //  clipBegin:30
    //, clipEnd:60
    //, autoRewind:false
    //, mbrStartingBitrate:3500
    //, mbrStartingIndex:2
    //, akamaiMediaType:'akamai-hdn-single-bitrate'
    //<----------------- HDN 1.0 CONFIG TAGS ---------------------------->
    // , startingBufferTime:5
    // , forceNoSubclip:true
    // , useMBRStartupBandwidthCheck:5
    //, primaryToken:'1336218178_ee70588889d6e859ffcd58c49c3872be'
    //<----------------- HDN 2.0 CONFIG TAGS ---------------------------->  
    //, addManifestQueryArgsToFragmentRequests:false
    //, enableLogStringOnFragments:false                    
    //, enableLargeBuffersForLongFormContent:false
    //, fragmentRetryAttemptsForLostConnectivity:120
    //, liveBufferProfile:'livelowlatency' // OR 'livestable'               
    //, useNetSession:true
    //, netsessionMode:'opportunistic'  //OR 'never'                                        
    //, enableNetSessionDiscovery:false
    //, playerVerificationChallenge:'salt'
    //<----------------- HDN 1.0 & 2.0 CONFIG TAGS ---------------------------->
    //, enableAlternateServerMapping:false
    //, enableEndUserMapping:false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use flashvars/variables in V6, but instead of using swfobject, you will have to use the JW Embedder (jwplayer.js).

Basically, in V6, the format is as follows:

variablename:'variablevalue',

Their provider is here - http://mediapm.edgesuite.net/jw/

We also have a V5 to V6 migration doc here - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28834/migrating-from-jw5-to-jw6

Hope this helps!

Comment: see my updated question, I am adding 'provider' as one of the variable

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, if you are using "provider" as one of the variables, I am not sure how that will work, as the "provider" variable does not exist in V6. You might want to consider also adding the "type" variable, and setting it to "mp4", that might work.